# How can i Transpose Mysql INSERT Statement?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i Transpose INSERT statement

Currently when insert my data in a table looks like this.

[image]

But I want to Insert as follows

```
 bomItem      partID
 600000      500000     
 600000      200000
 600000      100000
 600204      500210
 600204      201862
 600204      100202
 600206      500204
 600206      201748
 600206      100202
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
```

I have the following code to Insert data from one database to another(`Mysql`)table

```
 $recordd = $tv->search(3000254898, 's=2');

 foreach($recordd as $data2) {
  $itemid = $data2['fields']['STOCK NO'];
  $bomwheel = $data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN'];
  $bomtire = $data2['fields']['BOM TIRE PN'];
  $bomvalve = $data2['fields']['BOM VALVE PN'];
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO assy   (ItemID,bom1w,bom2t,bom3v) VALUES ($itemid, $bomwheel, $bomtire,$bomvalve)"); 
}
```

Comment: Insert the data into a different table that has two columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  but that doesn't rearrange the columns I want to Transpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way 3 insertion separately where $itemid would be same in all cases:

```
foreach($recordd as $data2) {
   $itemid = $data2['fields']['STOCK NO'];
   $bomwheel = $data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN'];
   $bomtire = $data2['fields']['BOM TIRE PN'];
   $bomvalve = $data2['fields']['BOM VALVE PN'];
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO assy(ItemID,bom1w) VALUES($itemid, $bomwheel)");
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO assy(ItemID,bom2t) VALUES($itemid, $bomtire)");
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO assy(ItemID,bom3v) VALUES($itemid, $bomvalve)"); 
}
```

Comment: added but one item

Comment: would you please share any php or mysql error  log here?

Comment: I think its working when i remove `id` the primary key - Auto Increament but that nothing to do with the data it exist only in the table. why is that?

Comment: and `recordLocator` is a unique identifier when data transpose it will duplicate the record/recordLocator field value how can i manage to use that as a unique identifier ?

Comment: Usually primary key is very essential one where querying by primary key faster than any other. And relational design has been so with the primary key.

Comment: to resist duplicate entry, you can create unique key by bomItem and partId.

Comment: Thats what i want, in Mysql Table?  how? sorry im a newbie

Comment: Please run this code at sql in phpmyadmin: ALTER TABLE <your_table_name> ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`bomItem`, `partid`);